# MYSQL: Query not properly accounting for max datetime column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I have a table `table1` `a_id` as `PK`,  `ipaddress`, `create_dt`
Here `ipaddress` is `varchar`, `create_dt` is `datetime`

```
a_id    ip              create_dt
9205    10.10.10.10     2017-01-07 08:03:32
9206    10.10.10.11     2017-01-06 08:03:32
9207    10.10.10.12     2015-01-07 08:03:32
```

---more than 1000 rows

I have another mysql table with following columns `id` as `PK`, `ip`, `check_type` `check_status`, `a_id` and `created_dt`:
Here `a_id` is foreign key from `table1`
and `timestamp_val` is `TIMESTAMP` field

```
id      ip             check_type    check_status  a_id    timestamp_val
1       10.10.10.10    check1        FAIL          9205    2017-01-07 10:03:32
2       10.10.10.10    check2        PASS          9205    2017-01-07 10:03:32
3       10.10.10.10    check1        FAIL          9205    2016-11-07 10:03:32
4       10.10.10.10    check2        PASS          9205    2016-11-07 10:03:32
5       10.10.10.11    check1        PASS          9206    2017-01-06 10:03:32
6       10.10.10.11    check2        PASS          9206    2015-01-06 10:03:32
```

I want all rows from `table1` where `date(create_dt) >= '2017-01-07'` and
`table1.a_id = table2.a_id` and `table2.check1 = 'FAIL'`
Also, `I only want to consider the row from table2` with latest `timestamp_val`

So from the above example, my query should return

```
a_id    ip              create_dt
9205    10.10.10.10     2017-01-07 08:03:32
```

I have written the following query but it is not always considering the rows from table2 with max 'timestamp_val'`

I am seeing values with older 'timestamp_val'` as well in some rows.

```
SELECT *  
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.a_id = b.a_id
WHERE a.create_dt >= '2017-01-07' AND
      b.check_status = 'FAIL' AND
      b.check_type = 'check1' AND
      b.timestamp_val = (SELECT MAX(b2.timestamp_val)
                         FROM table2 b2
                         WHERE b2.a_id = b.a_id AND
                               b2.check_status = b.check_status AND
                               b2.check_type = b.check_type
                        );
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try using a group  by based on the column you need   for obtain the max time  and join this result

```
SELECT *  
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.a_id = b.a_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.a_id, b2.check_status, b2.check_type, MAX(b2.timestamp_val) as max_time
  FROM table2 b2
  GROUP BY b2.a_id ,  b2.check_status ,  b2.check_type
  ) t on t.a_id = a.a_id  
      AND  t.check_status=b2.check_status 
      AND t.check_type =b2.check_type
      AND b.timestamp_val = t.max_time
WHERE a.create_dt >= '2017-01-07' AND
      b.check_status = 'FAIL' AND
      b.check_type = 'check1'
```

Comment: I am getting an error `Unknown column 'b2.check_status' in 'on clause'`

Comment: should it be  `AND  b.check_status=t.check_status 
      AND b.check_type =t.check_type`

Comment: I just checked timestamp_val is TIMESTAMP field It is not datetime field. also updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Try with this sub-query, now using the id instead the timestamp value:

```
b.id = (
    SELECT b2.id
    FROM table2 b2
    WHERE
        b2.a_id = b.a_id
        AND b2.check_status = b.check_status
        AND b2.check_type = b.check_type
    ORDER BY b2.timestamp_val desc limit 1
)
```

Comment: I am getting same result. Still seeing values with older 'timestamp_val'` as well in some rows.

Comment: timestamp_val is a datetime field?

Comment: I just checked `timestamp_val is TIMESTAMP field`  It is not `datetime` field. also updated my question

Comment: b.id = (
    SELECT b2.id
    FROM table2 b2
    WHERE
        b2.a_id = b.a_id
        AND b2.check_status = b.check_status
        AND b2.check_type = b.check_type
    ORDER BY b2.timestamp_val desc limit 1
)

Comment: By `b.id` do you mean `b.timestamp_val`? can i request you to update your answer to it is more clear? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change your timestamp_val to a DATETIME(6) - where it will show milliseconds.  Then, you will be able to sort by time correctly. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html